# How do I remove CSS from WordPress admin sections

Tags: wordpress, hook

I've been looking at the remove_action() call, which works for some elements, but I'm not sure it works for the CSS in the header.  I could manually edit the place where the CSS is loaded, but I'd rather do it through a plugin.

wp_admin_css_color

wp_admin_css

these are hooks that supposedly work, but I can't seem to figure out how use remove_action() on the hooks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress adds two default stylesheets (colors & wp-admin) to the admin area, you can deregister any stylesheet created by WordPress core, or any stylesheet created by a plugin using `wp_deregister_style('stylesheet_registered_name');`  the stylesheet name is its id="stylesheet-name" in the markup

to remove the 2 default admin stylesheets you can add something like the following code to your functions.php file or to a plugin.php file make sure to replace 'your' to a collision free prefix

```
    // this will remove the stylesheet when init fires
    add_action('admin_init','your_remove_default_stylesheets');
    // this is your function to deregister the default admin stylesheet
    function your_remove_default_stylesheets() {
    wp_deregister_style('wp-admin');
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so after looking a little further into it you can also use the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook to fire your function.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still helpful for anyone, I was able to make admin side completely match front end easily.

1) When you enqueue your theme or plugin styles, make sure to include admin_enqueue_scripts action to any styles you want to use on the backend.

2) In your global javascript, remove the classes 'wp-ui-core' and 'wp-admin' from the body.

```
jQuery('body').removeClass('wp-core-ui wp-admin');
```

So far I have found no detrimental side-effects.   The admin sidebar still loads and functions fine, and all of the admin pages look great, but now they match my theme instead of WP's design.

Answer (score 0):

This covers removing actions for themes: [Function Reference/remove action « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action). Don't know how relevant it is for WP's admin area.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with a solution to this, after much searching and trial and error.  To my knowledge, it's not in the WordPress codex anywhere, and when I brought it up in the WordPress IRC channels, some scoffed, as if the idea was just ridiculous.  I'll try and document it later when I have a chance, but I'll start by saying it involves creating your own functions.php file in your theme, and adding several instances of wp_deregister_style(), as well as a wp_admin_css hook to override the default theme.

Interestingly, I could *not* get this fix to work in a plugin, which was alright for my purposes since I have a highly modified theme, but I could imagine people wanting to just do it with a simple plugin.